# How can I sort a dictionary by value?

Tags: python

```
{'KRW-SOL': {'count': 3, 'tradeAmount': 437540}, 
'KRW-LOOM': {'count': 78, 'tradeAmount': 21030768}, 
'KRW-ONT': {'count': 14, 'tradeAmount': 947009}, 
'KRW-FCT2': {'count': 1, 'tradeAmount': 491935}, 
'KRW-DKA': {'count': 30, 'tradeAmount': 12053758}
```

I want to sort by count or tradeAmount

i want like this

```
{'KRW-LOOM': {'count': 78, 'tradeAmount': 21030768}, 
    'KRW-DKA': {'count': 30, 'tradeAmount': 12053758}
    'KRW-ONT': {'count': 14, 'tradeAmount': 947009}, 
    'KRW-SOL': {'count': 3, 'tradeAmount': 437540}, 
    'KRW-FCT2': {'count': 1, 'tradeAmount': 491935}}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a dictionary to be sorted. If you want to display it like this I think you must implement a custom function to print it in the correct order. But if you need sorted data consider if using an array might be a better option.

Comment: @JoelImbergamo It makes perfect sense for a dictionary to be sorted. Dictionaries have had insertion order since Python 3.7 (unofficially in CPython since 3.6).

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(cdDict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['tradeAmount'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: What is `cdDict`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below

```
x  = {'KRW-SOL': {'count': 3, 'tradeAmount': 437540}, 
'KRW-LOOM': {'count': 78, 'tradeAmount': 21030768}, 
'KRW-ONT': {'count': 14, 'tradeAmount': 947009}, 
'KRW-FCT2': {'count': 1, 'tradeAmount': 491935}, 
'KRW-DKA': {'count': 30, 'tradeAmount': 12053758}} #input

# new dict sorted by count
y = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['count'],reverse=True)}

print(y)
```

If you want sort by **tradeAmount** then,

```
y = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['tradeAmount'],reverse=True)}

print(y)
```

Comment: You don't need to do `{k: v for k, v in ...}`, the `dict` constructor already takes an iterable of pairs.